# Automate Add AD Users from CSV, archive CSV and delete CSV after Sucessful User Add using Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

I am trying to add users to active directory form CSV files dropped in a particular folder by using PowerShell script. This script will check AD if the users have been created and archive the CSV files before deleting them in readiness for another drops of CSV files. The power shell script will scheduled to process the CSV files dropped into the folder. I also want to user a separate but similar script to delete user from a CSV files using PowerShell.

Below are CSV  file content and my script. When running the file, there is no error or failure but I couldn't get any user created from the CSV file and no log file is created with the output redirect option 2>&1 and the CSV files are not being archived too.

CSV File content:

```
"givenName","displayName","sAMAccountName","EmailAddress","OU",password
"DummyUser","DummyUser","dummy.user.customer1.com","dummy.user@customer1.com","OU=customer1,OU=Customers,DC=customerservice,DC=customerdomain,DC=com","**********"
```

Powershell Script:

```
<# This script is used to add  Customers users in bulk to  active directory using CSV file
 This script will be scheduled to run every hour or everyday to add new  customer users to the AD  Customers OU
 A new AD User based attributes CSV file with .csv extension and  name format LDAP_Users***####.csv  must be placed in a shared folder called LDAPExport. The folder...
..LDAPExport is located in thg C: drive of the server.  Access to the folder from permitted servers is through the FTP server service running on this server where the script is running#>


try {
    set-location = c:\ldapexport  <# I just added this line after posting the question #>
    $CustomerAddADUserCSV = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ldapexport\ -Name *adduser*.csv
    $CustomerAddADUserLogFolder = "c:\ldapexport\CustomerADUsersLogs"
    $LdapExportLog = "c:\ldapexport\LdapExportLog"

  

<#the next lines check if AddUser csv file exists and then processed the file to add the Customer user/s account to Active Directory #>    
        if($CustomerAddADUserCSV){
               foreach ($CustomerCSVfile in $CustomeraddADUserCSV){
             
                 $NewADUsers = Import-Csv -Path $CustomerCSVfile ;
                 foreach ($User in $NewADUsers) 
                    {            
                    
                        $Displayname = $User.displayName            
                        $UserFirstname = $User.Firstname            
                        $UserLastname = $User.Lastname            
                        $OU = $User.OU            
                        $SAM = $User.sAMAccountName            
                        $Password = $User.Password
                        $EmailAddress = $User.EmailAddress
                                   
                        New-ADUser -Name "$Displayname" -DisplayName "$Displayname" -SamAccountName $SAM -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force) -Enabled $true -Path "$OU" -ChangePasswordAtLogon $false > "$LdapExportLog\csvdeAdUsers_$(get-date -f ddMMyyyy_HHmmss).log" 2>&1  -ErrorAction stop;
                        Get-ADUser -Identity $SAM -ErrorAction Stop > "$LdapExportLog\csvdeAdUsersAdded_$(get-date -f ddMMyyyy_HHmmss).log" 2>&1
                        } ;
            
          

<#the next lines archive the  AddUser csv files into a zipped files and store them the "Archive" located in the "ldapexport" directory.#>    
         
        
                $CustomerAddADUserCSVFileArchive = Compress-Archive -Path "C:\ldapexport\$CustomerCSVfile"  -DestinationPath C:\ldapexport\Archives\$CustomerCSVfile.$(get-date -f ddMMyyyy_HHmmss).zip -force;
               

                Compress-Archive -Path $CustomerAddADUserLogFolder  -DestinationPath C:\ldapexport\Archives\CustomerADUsersLogs_$(get-date -f ddMMyyyy_HHmmss).zip -force > $LdapExportLog\csvdeArchive_$(get-date -f ddMMyyyy_HHmmss).log 2>&1;


             }

         else{
                Write-Host "No new AddUser csv file exists. Quiting..." >  $LdapExportLog\csvdeAdUsers_$(get-date -f ddMMyyyy_HHmmss).log 2>&1;
                exit
             } 
            
       

    }
}


catch {
    write-host "Please, check the script of the referenced .csv file for any error logs"
    }
```

Comment: [New-ADUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/new-aduser?view=windowsserver2022-ps#outputs) does not output anything unless the PassThru parameter is specified. Please also have a look at how [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) works so you can abandon those horrible long lines and make the code much easier to read/maintain

Comment: Thanks, Theo. I have never heard about splatting before. I am reading up on it now. I will try to adopt  the style into my scripts. Its an hash table contained in a variable. I will see how I can manipulate the parameter values from spatting in a script. As for the output, I will PassThru parameter into this script and see if that helps.

Comment: I am getting somewhere with this script. I copied off the main part of the script below the "if" statement line and included all the three declared variables for the csv files on to the copied part and then ran in in PowerShell, I got files not found. I set the location to the path where the adduser*.csv files are and I am now see the error that were not showing before. It looks like the script was running from system32. I also noticed that the "if" statement is also referencing wrong variable "$CustomerADUserCSV" instead of "$CustomerAddADUserCSV"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a rewrite of your code.
I have changed some of the variable names because I found yours quite confusing sometimes.

Below code uses splatting on the New-ADUser cmdlet and collects the newly added user objects in a variable `$addedUsers`.
This collection is only outpout at the very end of the code instead of writing and compressing in each iteration.

```
$ArchivePath = 'C:\ldapexport\Archives'
$ErrorLog    = 'c:\ldapexport\LdapExportLog\csvdeAdUsers_{0:ddMMyyyy_HHmmss}.log' -f (Get-Date)
$NewUsersCsv = 'c:\ldapexport\LdapExportLog\csvdeAdUsersAdded_{0:ddMMyyyy_HHmmss}.csv' -f (Get-Date)

$addedUsers = foreach ($csvFile in (Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\ldapexport' -Filter '*adduser*.csv')) {
    $NewADUsers = Import-Csv -Path $csvFile.FullName
    foreach ($User in $NewADUsers) {
        $userParams = @{
            Name                  = $User.displayName
            SamAccountName        = $User.sAMAccountName
            DisplayName           = $User.displayName
            GivenName             = $User.Firstname
            Surname               = $User.Lastname
            EmailAddress          = $User.EmailAddress
            Path                  = $User.OU
            AccountPassword       = ConvertTo-SecureString $User.Password -AsPlainText -Force
            Enabled               = $true
            ChangePasswordAtLogon = $false
            ErrorAction           = 'Stop'
            PassThru              = $true
        }
        # try to create the new user and output the properties to be collected in variable $addedUsers
        try {
            New-ADUser @userParams
        }
        catch {
            $msg = "Error creating user $($User.sAMAccountName): $($_.Exception.Message)"
            # write to the error log
            $msg | Add-Content -Path $ErrorLog
            Write-Warning $msg
        }
    }

    # create the full path for the archive file and compress this current imported csv file
    $archiveFile = Join-Path -Path $ArchivePath -ChildPath ('{0}.{1:ddMMyyyy_HHmmss}.zip' -f $csvFile.BaseName, (Get-Date))
    Compress-Archive -Path $csvFile.FullName -DestinationPath $archiveFile
    # remove the current csv file
    $csvFile | Remove-Item
}

# here, you save the newly added users collected in variable $addedUsers
$addedUsers | Export-Csv -Path $NewUsersCsv -NoTypeInformation
# if you want, compress this file and archive
# create the full path for the archive file and compress
$archiveFile = Join-Path -Path $ArchivePath -ChildPath ('{0}.zip' -f [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($NewUsersCsv))
Compress-Archive -Path $NewUsersCsv -DestinationPath $archiveFile
# remove the newusers csv file?
$NewUsersCsv | Remove-Item
```